# how to specialize the template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

consider existing situation

```
template<typename T, int N = 10>
struct A
{
    //whatever
};

template <typename T1,typename T2, typename T3>
struct B;

template<typename T2, typename T3>
struct B<double,T2,T3>
{
    //...

protected:
   A<T2> myA;
};
```

Now I'm interesting to be able to pass different than the default `N` to `A` in  specialization of `B` without changing the declaration of `B`. Is it possible?

I can think about

```
template<typename T2, typename T3, int N>
struct B<double,T2,T3>
{
    //...

protected:
    A<T2,N> myA;
};
```

but then I'm not sure how to use it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your class `B` is only usable like that:

```
B<double, C, D> b;
```

Where `C`and `D` are types themselves.

You cannot pass a number there. Specialization won't help you. Specialization don't change how you can use the class or what parameters you can pass, but you can only change what the implementation for a certain set of parameter. With that said,

What I suggest is to change the declaration of `B` to be like:

```
template <typename, typename, typename, int = 10>
struct B;
```

Ans the specialization to be like that:

```
template<typename T2, typename T3, int N>
struct B<double,T2,T3, N> {
    //...

protected:
    A<T2, N> myA;
};
```

So your class is both useable like before, and like this:

```
B<double, C, D, 11> b;
```

---

If you really cannot change what the parameter are, you can further specialize it to recieve a type that has a number as template parameter:

```
template<typename, int>
struct TypeAndNumber {};
```

And change your socialization to that:

```
template<typename T2, typename T3, int N>
struct B<TypeAndNumber<double, N>, T2, T3> {
    //...

protected:
    A<T2, N> myA;
};
```

Now your class can be useable like that:

```
B<TypeAndNumber<double, 33>, C, B> b;
```

Comment: the second part is what I was looking for, actually I started to think in this direction and you beat me:)